# Ember.js - add record request has blank parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-cli

I am using ember-cli with a Rails API backend and am having some issues adding a new record.

I've set up the form and route and am able to retrieve the values from the form, but the save() does not pass these values back to the POST request for Rails, resulting in a blank record being created.

I would appreciate any assistance at all.

Adapter application.js:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api'
});
```

Route:

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
  model() {
    //return this.store.createRecord('book');
    return {};
  },

  actions: {
    saveBook(newBook) {
      var curr = this.store.createRecord('book', {
        title: newBook.title,
        author: newBook.author,
        genre: newBook.genre
      });
      alert("curr.title = " + curr.title);
      curr.save();
      this.transitionTo('books');
    },
  }
});
```

Template:

```
<h2>Add Book</h2>

<div class="layout-row">
  {{!-- {{book-form model=model buttonLabel="Add Book" action='saveBook'}} --}}
  <div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="layout-row">
      <div class="layout-column flex-200">
      {{paper-input label="Title" value=model.title onChange=(action (mut model.title))}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="layout-row">
      <div class="layout-column flex-200">
      {{paper-input label="Author" value=model.author onChange=(action (mut model.author))}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="layout-row">
      <div class="layout-column flex-200">
      {{paper-input label="Genre" value=model.genre onChange=(action (mut model.genre))}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="layout-row">
      <button type="submit" {{action "saveBook" model}}>Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Browser result using Ember Inspector:

```
{"data":{"id":"31","type":"books","attributes":{"title":null,"author":null,"genre":null}}}
```

Comment: You have included the payload of your APIs response, isn't it? Would be helpful to see the payload of your client request to ensure that it's not a backend issue. Also it would be helpful to know what the value of `newBook` passed to `saveBook` action is. Hard to tell if it's an issue with `paper-input` or `book-form` component otherwise.

Comment: The payload above is from the client request.

Comment: Are you sure? You must have a very uncommon way of generating client-side IDs If this payload is from the client request (and not from the server reponse). ID `31` looks like an auto incremented ID applied your server not like a client-side generated ID, which is usually a GUID.

Comment: @jelhan you are correct...that is not the client request.  I'm  not sure how to locate the correct value...can you give me a tip?

Comment: Further investigation has revealed that the client request does in fact contain the correct values.
The issue is now that those parameters are not passed to or accepted by Rails at all.

Comment: So this is not related to ember code at all.

Comment: Not that I can currently see.  I'm having difficulty working out exactly where it is falling down, but when I have more information I will update.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer adding the action to a form on submit action as then your form will submit when enter or save are pressed.

```
<h2>Add Book</h2>

<div class="layout-row">

  <form class="form-horizontal" {{action "saveBook" on="submit"}}>
    <div class="layout-row">
      <div class="layout-column flex-200">
      {{paper-input label="Title" value=model.title onChange=(action (mut model.title))}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="layout-row">
      <div class="layout-column flex-200">
      {{paper-input label="Author" value=model.author onChange=(action (mut model.author))}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="layout-row">
      <div class="layout-column flex-200">
      {{paper-input label="Genre" value=model.genre onChange=(action (mut model.genre))}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="layout-row">
      <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Route:

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.store.createRecord('book');
  }
});
```

Controller:

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';

export default Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    saveBook() {
      this.model.save().then(() => {
        this.transitionTo('books');
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: You should ensure that the record is removed from store if user leaves the route without saving it. Otherwise you will end up with dummy records in store which must be filtered out in each Ember Data request that may be served from local cache.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not help...the submit did not pick up the form values and pass them to the backend, resulting in a blank record being created once more.